# JSON file parsing issue

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a json file which i am trying to parse in **snowflake database**.
I am able to parse all node except rules .

**I am not able to parse rules node correctly.**
below node

```
"rules":{"540828":"Store_App_Fingerprint","576196":"App_email_domain"}
```

Please help if i am missing something.

file structure is something like this.

```
{"country":"","auto":"R","orderNumber":"contraact123","language":"","rules":{"540828":"Store_App_Fingerprint","576196":"App_email_domain"},"deviceLayers":"...."
,"mode":"Q","score":"29","merchantId":"124300","vmax":"0","warningCount":0,"brand":"NONE","errorCount":0,"knowYourCustomer":"N","kaptcha":"N","counters":{},
"pcRemote":"","devices":"1""fingerPrint":""}
```

Code i tried.

```
select v.pkey as pkey,
parse_json(v.content):country::string as country ,
parse_json(v.content):auto::string as auto ,
parse_json(v.content):orderNumber::string as orderNumber 
,parse_json(v.content):language::string as language
,parse_json(v.content):rules::string as rules,
 parse_json(v.content):App_email_domain::string as App_email_domain ,
parse_json(v.content):deviceLayers::string as deviceLayers
```

May someone please share your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with the JSON provided by you:

---

There is `,` missing between `devices` & `fingerPrint` tags

> "devices":"1""fingerPrint":""

---

Your `rules` tag is like following

```
  "rules": {
      "540828":"Store_App_Fingerprint",
      "576196":"App_email_domain"
  }
```

---

As you can see the key is `540828` & `576196` and not `Store_App_Fingerprint` & `App_email_domain`.

If you want to access `rules.App_email_domain`, you need to change your JSON like following:

```
"rules": {
    "Store_App_Fingerprint":"540828",
    "App_email_domain":"576196"
}
```

Since you are trying to select nest element, you should be using `.` notation to navigate to specific field.

e.g.

Current: `parse_json(column1):App_email_domain::string as App_email_domain`

Updated: `parse_json(column1):rules.App_email_domain::string as App_email_domain`

Here is the working example:

```
SELECT
    parse_json(column1):country::string as country
  , parse_json(column1):auto::string as auto
  , parse_json(column1):orderNumber::string as orderNumber 
  , parse_json(column1):language::string as language
  , parse_json(column1):rules::string as rules
  , parse_json(column1):rules.App_email_domain::string as App_email_domain
  , parse_json(column1):deviceLayers::string as deviceLayers
FROM VALUES
('{
    "country": "",
    "auto": "R",
    "orderNumber": "contraact123",
    "language": "",
    "rules": {
        "Store_App_Fingerprint": "540828",
        "App_email_domain": "576196"
    },
    "deviceLayers": "....",
    "mode": "Q",
    "score": "29",
    "merchantId": "124300",
    "vmax": "0",
    "warningCount": 0,
    "brand": "NONE",
    "errorCount": 0,
    "knowYourCustomer": "N",
    "kaptcha": "N",
    "counters": {},
    "pcRemote": "",
    "devices": "1",
    "fingerPrint": ""
}') v;
```

Result:

```
+---------+------+--------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
| COUNTRY | AUTO | ORDERNUMBER  | LANGUAGE | RULES                                                          | APP_EMAIL_DOMAIN | DEVICELAYERS |
+---------+------+--------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
|         | R    | contraact123 |          | {"App_email_domain":"576196","Store_App_Fingerprint":"540828"} | 576196           | ....         |
+---------+------+--------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
```